# QGIS styles: How to reset default saved style in Local database

Tags: qgis

**What do I have:**

QGIS 2.16.2 / WIN7

I defined a style on a PostGIS layer which I saved as default in the Datasource database. This works quite nice!

**What do I need:**

Now I want to create the style from scratch but I have a hard time 'resetting' the style. After deleting the record in public.layer_styles the style still loads with the layer on my system, but not on other systems. Also does load with user login, but not with admin login. So I suspect I saved the style by accident in the Local database as well. Where to find this 'Local database' and how do I remove the style from it?

[image]

**What have I tried:**

- Searched the QGIS settings.
- Browsed to ....qgis2\ and viewed the SpatialLite databases with FME. No answers found.
- Copy the table in PostGIS, add to QGIS, copy default style and paste to original table, save as default in local database. This works for me now but I still would like to know where the style is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of anyone else landing here like I did, in QGIS3 the "local database" is qgis.qmldb within the QGIS profile folder.

I don't know where it was in QGIS2.

You can drag and drop it into QGIS, find the right entry and delete it.  Unfortunately it is very slow to work with in QGIS - perhaps because a QML is an unusually large amount of data to store in a field.  And I don't know if QGIS ever garbage collects the database, but I was able to "compact" a copy using the QGIS browser panel, after changing the file extension to .db